# If I will Pay for Magento 2 Professional Developer Certification Exam to Magento Then Magento will Provide me Study Materials?

Tags: magento2, certification

I want to take to the exam of the Magento 2 Professional Developer Certification.
I am Finding Study Materials for Preparing Exam. Magento Take Fee $260 for Exam and Certificat. I have one Question that they will Provide me any video tutorials or any Special books for Preparing Exam and Easy way to understand the flow and structure of Magento.

Comment: I think no.....

Comment: thank u, but provide me the best tutorials for learning magento faster for certification Exam.

Comment: M2 certification is not a faster thing. You need to more working experience than memorizing.

Comment: thanks for guiding me but please provide some resource that will very useful for the pass certification exam.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no.

There are resources out there

https://swiftotter.com/technical/certifications/magento-2-certified-developer-study-guide#/

For example

I can only reiterate what someone else has said. I'd be wary of this certification. You will gain more by putting together magento builds.